# How to merge values with same keys in a nested dictionary? (Nothing works)

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, merge, key

First thing's first I am new to Python programming so any help is GREATLY appreciated. I am having issues combining the same key values from different dictionaries so that it is a single key value pair. I tried many solutions offered on here but none of them seem to work for my case. I know I am doing something wrong. The output is derived from parsing two separate text based configurations. It all ends up in the same giant masterDict dictionary. I can change this so that each file generates a separate dictionary, but I want this to be scalable for up to 4 nested dictionaries. 0 would be first file and 1 is the second. Here's a summarized version of the dictionary.

```
masterDict = {0: {'access': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' switchport access vlan 532'},
     'description': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' description Printer'},
     'duplex': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' duplex half'},
     'speed': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' speed 10'},
     'trunk': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': 'switchport mode trunk'}},
 1: {'access': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' switchport access vlan 532'},
     'description': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' description Printer'},
     'duplex': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' duplex half'},
     'speed': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' speed 10'},
     'trunk': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': 'switchport mode trunk'}}}
```

What I would like the end result to look like is as follows:

```
newMasterDict = {0: {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': [' switchport access vlan 532',
                                      ' description Printer',
                                      ' duplex half',
                                      ' speed 10',
                                      'switchport mode trunk']},
 1: {'newDict': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': [' switchport access vlan 532',
                                                  ' description Printer',
                                                  ' duplex half',
                                                  ' speed 10',
                                                  'switchport mode trunk']}}}
```

Please note that the keys will not be present in every dictionary. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Here is how the masterDict is generated:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
from collections import defaultdict
homepath = 'c:/Users/c_eavila/Box/Projects/Environment1/'
pathList = ("testconfig.txt", "testconfig2.txt")
queryList = ('description', 'speed', 'duplex')
swpModes = ("access", "trunk")

masterDict = {}
masterDict2 = {}
for count, path in enumerate(pathList):
  dictList = {}
  loadParse = CiscoConfParse(config=homepath+path , ignore_blank_lines=True, syntax='ios')
  for mode in swpModes:
    if mode == "access":
      parentParse = loadParse.find_parents_w_child(r'^interface', r'switchport mode '+mode)
      accVlanParse = loadParse.find_children_w_parents(r'^interface', r'switchport access vlan')
      accVlanDict = dict(zip(parentParse, accVlanParse))
      dictList['access'] = accVlanDict
    elif mode == "trunk":
      v = 'switchport mode trunk'
      parentParse = loadParse.find_parents_w_child(r'^interface', r'switchport mode '+mode)
      trunkAllowedParse = loadParse.find_children_w_parents(r'^interface', r'switchport trunk allowed')
      if trunkAllowedParse != []:
        trunkAllowedDict = dict(zip(parentParse, trunkAllowedParse))
        trunkDict = dict(zip(parentParse, 'switchport mode trunk',))
        dictList['trunkallowed'] = trunkAllowedDict
        dictList['trunk'] = {k:v for k in trunkDict}
      elif trunkAllowedParse == []:
        trunkDict = dict(zip(parentParse, 'switchport mode trunk',))
        dictList['trunk'] = {k:v for k in trunkDict}
    for query in queryList:
      parentParse = loadParse.find_parents_w_child(r'^interface', query)
      childParse = loadParse.find_children_w_parents(r'^interface', query)
      dictList[query] = dict(zip(parentParse, childParse))
  masterDict[count] = dictList
```

Here's an excerpt of the config. Feel free to copy, paste, and try it out yourself. The objective is to only pull queried lines.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 532
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 532
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 description UPS
 switchport access vlan 15
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 532
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 description Office 207 port 226a Plotter
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 speed 10
 duplex full
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 532
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
 description Printer Ray Rm 210
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 532
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 45
 switchport port-security maximum 50
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 5
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 auto qos voip cisco-phone 
 spanning-tree portfast
```

Edit: Just wanted to give a huge thanks to @GhandiFloss and @JoshuaSundance for being helpful. @GhandiFloss 's solution seems to work for my summarized dictionary I posted above. However, it does not work for my full dictionary. I am trying to tweak the code so that it does. Again, any point to the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!
Here's the full dict: note it may be up to twice as big as this dict was generated from two nearly identical configurations. I want to be able to do up to 4.

```
masterDict = {0: {'access': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/10': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/11': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/12': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/13': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/14': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/15': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/16': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/17': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/18': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/19': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/20': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/21': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/22': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/23': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/24': ' switchport access vlan 598',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/25': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/26': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/27': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/28': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/29': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/3': ' switchport access vlan 15',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/30': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/31': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/32': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/33': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/34': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/35': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/37': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/38': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/39': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/4': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/40': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/41': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/42': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/43': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/44': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/45': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/46': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/47': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/48': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/6': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/7': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/8': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/9': ' switchport access vlan 50'},
     'description': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/13': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/14': ' description Printer '
                                                      '216',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/17': ' description bpdu '
                                                      '8-19-20 cp',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/18': ' description FMA 200A '
                                                      'Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/20': ' description Printer '
                                                      '209',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/24': ' description Wireless',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/25': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/26': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/27': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/28': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/3': ' description UPS',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/35': ' description FMA '
                                                      'Printer 204',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/37': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/40': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/41': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/45': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' description Office 207 '
                                                     'port 226a Plotter',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' description trunktest',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/7': ' description Printer Ray '
                                                     'Rm 210',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/9': ' description Printer 213',
                     'interface Vlan1000': ' description Management VLAN'},
     'duplex': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' duplex half',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' duplex full',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' duplex full'},
     'speed': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' speed 10',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' speed 10',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' speed 100'},
     'trunk': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/49': ' switchport mode trunk',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/50': ' switchport mode trunk',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' switchport mode trunk'},
     'trunkallowed': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/49': ' switchport trunk '
                                                       'allowed vlan 50'}},
 1: {'access': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/1': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/10': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/11': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/12': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/13': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/14': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/15': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/16': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/17': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/18': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/19': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/2': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/20': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/21': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/22': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/23': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/24': ' switchport access vlan 598',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/25': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/26': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/27': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/28': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/29': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/3': ' switchport access vlan 15',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/30': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/31': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/32': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/33': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/34': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/35': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/37': ' switchport access vlan 64',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/38': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/39': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/4': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/40': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/41': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/42': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/43': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/44': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/45': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/46': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/47': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/48': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/6': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/7': ' switchport access vlan 50',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/8': ' switchport access vlan 532',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/9': ' switchport access vlan 50'},
     'description': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/13': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/14': ' description Printer '
                                                      '216',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/17': ' description bpdu '
                                                      '8-19-20 cp',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/18': ' description FMA 200A '
                                                      'Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/20': ' description Printer '
                                                      '209',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/24': ' description Wireless',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/25': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/26': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/27': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/28': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/3': ' description UPS',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/35': ' description FMA '
                                                      'Printer 204',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/37': ' description Camera',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/40': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/41': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/45': ' description Printer',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' description Office 207 '
                                                     'port 226a Plotter',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' description trunktest',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/7': ' description Printer Ray '
                                                     'Rm 210',
                     'interface GigabitEthernet0/9': ' description Printer 213',
                     'interface Vlan1000': ' description Management VLAN'},
     'duplex': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' duplex half',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' duplex full',
                'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' duplex full'},
     'speed': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/36': ' speed 10',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/5': ' speed 10',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' speed 100'},
     'trunk': {'interface GigabitEthernet0/49': ' switchport mode trunk',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/50': ' switchport mode trunk',
               'interface GigabitEthernet0/51': ' switchport mode trunk'}}}
```

Comment: Can you show how the initial masterDict is being generated?

Comment: Just edited my post. Let me know if something is unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the massive dict you posted. As I said its a mess and needs some work but it should help. This took me a while but it was annoying me so wanted to complete it !

```
def seperate_dicts(dicts):
  dict_list = []
  keys = list(dicts.keys())
  for key in keys:
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict[key] = dicts[key]
    dict_list.append(new_dict)
    new_dict = {}
  return dict_list


def get_attribs(dict_list):
  new_main = {}
  key = list(dict_list[0].keys())[0]
  new_main['newDict'] = dict_list[0][key]
  for i in range(1, len(dict_list)):
    other_key = list(dict_list[i].keys())[0]
    other_keys = list(dict_list[i][other_key])
    for key2 in other_keys:
      if key2 not in new_main['newDict']:
        new_main['newDict'][key2] = dict_list[i][other_key][key2]
      elif isinstance(new_main['newDict'][key2], list):
        new_main['newDict'][key2].append(dict_list[i][other_key][key2])
      else:
        new_main['newDict'][key2] = [
            new_main['newDict'][key2], dict_list[i][other_key][key2]]
  return new_main

new_master = {}

for i in range(len(masterDict)):
  dict_list = seperate_dicts(masterDict[i])
  res = get_attribs(dict_list)
  new_master[i] = res

print(new_master)
```

Comment: Hello,

This worked on a new file! However, on my generated masterDict, it does not work. It throws the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/c_eavila/Box/Projects/Environment1/cisco_conf_parse_test.py", line 46, in <module>
    listofattribs.append(inner_dict[key][inner_key])
KeyError: 'interface GigabitEthernet0/1'

Comment: It is probably getting hung up on the increment of the key from 0/1 to 0/2 try my edit

Comment: Same error :(. I'm definitely generating my dictionary wrong. Trying to see how I can generate it properly.

Comment: Hello. I tried copying and pasting my generated dict and it's still the same error. I just realized it's because it's not going to work on my generated dict since it has many more inner keys. How would I rewrite your code so that it can loop through all keys in my inner dicts? Thanks!

Comment: Ok so i think i may have a solution, it took me a while and the code is a mess and needs refactoring but it will give you something. I will edit now.

Comment: Thanks so much! I won't be using this parser anymore in the future. It's too limited. At least I got to understand python dictionaries much bettter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

(edit): After reviewing your comments and thinking more about your needs, what about something more like this?

```
# ls will be a list of dicts where each dict represents an interface
ls = []

# testconf is the configuration file from your question
# split it into chunks seperated by the exclamation points
for i in testconf.split('!'):
    d = {}
    # split each chunk into lines
    for l in i.split('\n'):
        l = l.strip()
        if l != '':
            for s in ['interface', 'switchport mode', 'description', 'speed', 'duplex']:
                # if the line starts with the word
                if l.startswith(s):
                    # if the word is already in d
                    if s in d.keys():
                        # if it's not a list
                        if not type(d[s])==list:
                            d[s] = [d[s], l.replace(s,'').strip()]
                        else:
                        # if it is a list
                            d[s].append(l.replace(s,'').strip())
                    # if the word is not already in d
                    else:
                            d[s] = l.replace(s,'').strip()
    # add d to ls
    ls.append(d)
    
access = [d for d in ls if 'access' in list(d.values())]
trunk = [d for d in ls if 'trunk' in list(d.values())]

print(trunk)
print('\n\n\n')
print(access)
```

Output:

```
[{'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/49', 'switchport mode': 'trunk'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/50', 'switchport mode': 'trunk'},
 {'description': 'trunktest',
  'duplex': 'full',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/51',
  'speed': '100',
  'switchport mode': 'trunk'}]




[{'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/1', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/2', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'UPS',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/3',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/4', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Office 207 port 226a Plotter',
  'duplex': 'full',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/5',
  'speed': '10',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/6', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer Ray Rm 210',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/7',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/8', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer 213',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/9',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/10', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/11', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/12', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/13',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer 216',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/14',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/15', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/16', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'bpdu 8-19-20 cp',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/17',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'FMA 200A Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/18',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/19', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer 209',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/20',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/21', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/22', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/23', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Wireless',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/24',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/25',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Camera',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/26',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Camera',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/27',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Camera',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/28',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/29', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/30', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/31', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/32', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/33', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/34', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'FMA Printer 204',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/35',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Camera',
  'duplex': 'half',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/36',
  'speed': '10',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Camera',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/37',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/38', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/39', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/40',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/41',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/42', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/43', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/44', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'description': 'Printer',
  'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/45',
  'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/46', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/47', 'switchport mode': 'access'},
 {'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/48', 'switchport mode': 'access'}]
```

(old post): I'm not sure exactly what you'd like, as your desired end result contains syntax errors. How about something like this, as a starting point?

```
def newd(d):
    nk = list(list(d.values())[0].keys())[0]
    nd = {}
    nd['interface'] = nk.replace('interface ','').strip()
    for k,v in d.items():
        nd[k] = v[nk].replace(k,'').strip()
    return nd

{k:newd(v) for k,v in masterDict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: {'access': 'switchport  vlan 532',
     'description': 'Printer',
     'duplex': 'half',
     'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/1',
     'speed': '10',
     'trunk': 'switchport mode'},
 1: {'access': 'switchport  vlan 532',
     'description': 'Printer',
     'duplex': 'half',
     'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/2',
     'speed': '10',
     'trunk': 'switchport mode'}}
```

Comment: There's definitely syntax errors in my dictionary generation. I'm currently taking a look to see how I could fix it. It seems like my generated dictionary is the issue.

Comment: Also, I get the same KeyError on your code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/c_eavila/Box/Projects/Environment1/cisco_conf_parse_test.py", line 48, in <module>
    {k:newd(v) for k,v in masterDict.items()}
  File "c:/Users/c_eavila/Box/Projects/Environment1/cisco_conf_parse_test.py", line 48, in <dictcomp>
    {k:newd(v) for k,v in masterDict.items()}
  File "c:/Users/c_eavila/Box/Projects/Environment1/cisco_conf_parse_test.py", line 45, in newd
    nd[k] = v[nk].replace(k,'').strip()
KeyError: 'interface GigabitEthernet0/1'

Comment: I just realized that my output dict functions like a list rather than a dict lol. To clarify though, my code works fine on the masterDict as defined at the top of your post. 

```print(newmasterDict[0])```

```{'interface': 'GigabitEthernet0/1', 'access': 'switchport  vlan 532', 'description': 'Printer', 'duplex': 'half', 'speed': '10', 'trunk': 'switchport mode'}```

Comment: It does! I am generating my dictionary wrong. I literally copied and pasted the formatting. However it seems that there's an underlying issue with how it's encoded. I did get constant errors before saying it was wrong data type when I would use other solutions for merging. Not sure though

Comment: Maybe we should start over with what you have (ie the conf file?) and what you need (ie how you want your dict structured)

Comment: Yes. I'm going over the code step by step. It must be whenever I am extracting the config lines and creating a dict from them. I thought using dict() it would format everything properly but it isn't. And what I want returned is the interface, and the "sub-configs" under the interface. Anything that contains what's in my queryList. as well  as anything that starts with "switchport mode ". I would want to separate it into two dictionaries. One for "switchport mode access" and the other for "switchport mode trunk". So I can apply the proper configuration on my jinja template.

Comment: Please see edit on my original response & see if that's helpful at all

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I am not sure how to pull the config from my text file. Also, I'm not sure if your formatting will play nice when I try to process it in my jinja template. the end goal is to have all these configuration lines and interlace them with a set of commands our organization uses for access and trunk ports. UGH! I'll take a look at this later tonight. We're so close. Thanks again. I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sure we can help you restructure your dict, but as I said previously the desired end result in your post is not a valid dict. If you copy and paste it into a python interpreter, there's a syntax error. What would the desired output look like? A dictionary? A list of strings?

Comment: Right. My bad for not addressing that. Please see my edit.